# Removing Rows based on criteria using python

Tags: pandas

This is just a dummy data, the actual data has over 9,000 rows.

The goal is to remove all the rows with `wit (Rev)` in Desc columns and also remove the row that `Ref_ID` matches those with `wit (Rev)` in Desc columns. The index of the desired result would be

`0,2,3,6,8,9,10,11`.

NOTE: using drop_duplicate will remove index 10, 11 which is wrong. The identifiers to use while dropping the rows should be either Desc or Ref_ID.

```py
dfA = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['ada', 'john', 'Jane', 'james', 'cain', 'mary','luke', 'samuel', 'moses', 'paris','moses','moses','john', 'Godwin', 'mary', 'Blessing'],
                    'Age': [10,20,30,40,23,33,56,32,12,45,12,12, 20,23,70,50],
                    'Ref_ID': [2345675,9876542,4567235, 2345867, 090988,8076546,1240986, 1022022, 3203323,7067554,3203323,3203323,876542,8090988,8076546,1022022],
                    'Desc': ['Wit', 'Wit', 'Wit', 'Wit', 'Wit', 'Wit', 'Wit', 'Wit','Wit', 'Wit', 'wit', 'wit','Wit (Rev)', 'Wit (Rev)','Wit (Rev)', 'Wit (Rev)']},
                    columns = ['Name', 'Age', 'Ref_ID', 'Desc'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your code is but the problem with rows with indexes 10,11 is probably because the value of Desc column in these rows are small letter 'wit', while this value is 'Wit' in other columns and you are probably comparing on the basis of 'Wit' value not 'wit'

```py
#matches array gives the index of those rows in Desc column with value "Wit (Rev)"
matches = []
matches = dfA.index[dfA['Desc'] == 'Wit (Rev)'].tolist()
#Ref_IDs stores the Ref_IDs of Ref_IDs column that should be removed
Ref_IDs = [] 
for i in matches: 
    Ref_IDs.append(dfA.iloc[i]['Ref_ID'])
dfA[dfA.isin({'Ref_ID': Ref_IDs})['Ref_ID'] == False]
```

The last line first checks if the column `Ref_ID` has any value among those in `Ref_IDs` array and then

```py
dfA.isin({'Ref_ID': Ref_IDs})['Ref_ID']
```

returns a column of **False** and **True** values, when the value is not in **Ref_IDs** this column is False and we exactly want the dataset rows which their `Ref_ID` value is not in **Ref_IDs** which we want to remove. the output is:

```py
     Name  Age   Ref_ID Desc
0     ada   10  2345675  Wit
1    john   20  9876542  Wit
2    Jane   30  4567235  Wit
3   james   40  2345867  Wit
4    cain   23    90988  Wit
6    luke   56  1240986  Wit
8   moses   12  3203323  Wit
9   paris   45  7067554  Wit
10  moses   12  3203323  wit
11  moses   12  3203323  wit
```